# How do I combine date from one timestamp and time from another timestamp?

Tags: java, datetime

I using AngularJS to get date and time separately as user input through via HTML. But timestamp is a single column in my database.

Date and Time field are coming as two different timestamps in my Java server.

```
Date --> 2015-11-11 00:00:00.0
Time --> 1970-01-01 23:11:00.0
```

I want to combine date part from Date and time part from Time and insert as timestamp into my database

```
DateTime --> 2015-11-11 23:11:00.0
```

Comment: are you using JodaTime library?

Comment: @NiteshVirani No I have not used any external library.

Comment: Do you know if these values are in UTC time zone?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're able to create these as `java.util.Date` objects, you can rely on their milleseconds-from-epoch to get this information:

```
long dateMills = date.getTime();
long timeMills = time.getTime();

long dateTimeMills = dateMills + timeMills();

long dateTime = new Date(dateTimeMills);
```

Alternatively, you could set the fields individually.

```
GregorianCalendar dateCal = new GregorianCalendar();
GregorianCalendar timeCal = new GregorianCalendar();

dateCal.setTime(date.getTime());
timeCal.setTime(time.getTime());

int year = dateCal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = dateCal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int day = dateCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

int hour = timeCal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minute = timeCal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int second = timeCal.get(Calendar.SECOND);

GregorianCalendar dateTimeCal = new GregorianCaledar(year, month, day, hour, minute, second);
Date dateTime = dateTimeCal.getTime();
```

Comment: You should not be using GregorianCalendar directly. Instead call Calendar.getInstance()

Answer (score 2):

No need to use the date and time as String, just use Calendar and get the fields separately:

```
public static Date combineDateTime(Date date, Date time) {
    Calendar dateCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    dateCalendar.setTime(date);

    Calendar timeCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    timeCalendar.setTime(time);

    dateCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, timeCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR));
    dateCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timeCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    dateCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, timeCalendar.get(Calendar.SECOND));

    return dateCalendar.getTime();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use String.split and create your required String date and use it as required.

```
 SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
 SimpleDateFormat formatter2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
 String dateInString = "12:30 AM";
 String dateInString2 = "2017-10-16 10:00:00";
 try {
  Date date1 = formatter.parse(dateInString);
  Date date2 = formatter2.parse(dateInString2);
  String[] d1 = formatter2.format(date1).split(" ");
  String[] d2 = formatter2.format(date2).split(" ");
  String neededDate = d2[0] + " " + d1[1];
  System.out.println(date1);
  System.out.println(formatter2.format(date1));
  System.out.println(formatter2.format(date2));
  System.out.println(neededDate);
 } catch (ParseException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Output

```
Thu Jan 01 00:30:00 IST 1970
1970-01-01 00:30:00
2017-10-16 10:00:00
2017-10-16 00:30:00
```